# How to create a lists of matrices?

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation, sparse-arrays

I would like to creat a list of matrices from the following rules:

1- All matrices of the list have diagonal equal to zero.

2- The first matrix have 2x2 dimension, `startmatrix={{0,1},{0,0}}`

3- The next matrix have 3x3 dimensions and the submatrix have same elements of the matrix write in step 2; the other elements are Random Integers [1,3 -1]; 3 = dimension of the matrix in the step;

4- The next matrix have dimension 4x4; repeat the same elements of the step 3 and other elements is Random Integer [1,4-1]; 4= dimension of the matrix in the step;

For instance: look the figure below

[image]

I  thought in the code below, but it not repeat the elements of previous matrix

```
nmax = 15 ;(*number of matrices*)
startMatrix = {{0, 1}, {0, 0}} ;(*The matrix begin*)
d = 2;(*Dimension of the first matrix*)
f[i_, j_] := 
 If[i <= d && j <= d, startMatrix[[i, j]], 
  If[j > i, RandomInteger[{1, j - d}], RandomInteger[{1, i - d}]]](*The rule for to create the matrices*)
m1 = Table[
  SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> 0, {i_, j_} -> f[i, j]}, {n, n}], {n, d, 
   nmax}](*Obtain the list of matrices*)

Table[MatrixForm[m1[[i]]], {i, nmax - 1}] (*Show the matrix form of the all matrices of the list*)
```

Please, anybody help me?

Answer (score 3):

You may use [`ArrayFlatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayFlatten.html) and [`NestList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html).

With

```
SeedRandom[123];
nmax = 4;
startMatrix = {{0, 1}, {0, 0}};
```

Then

```
m1 =
  NestList[
   With[{rand = RandomInteger[{1, Length[#] + 1}, {2, Length[#]}]},
     ArrayFlatten[{
       {#, Partition[rand[[1]], 1]},
       {{rand[[2]]}, {{0}}}
       }]
     ] &
   ,
   startMatrix,
   nmax - 1
   ];

MatrixForm /@ m1
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

This has the added benefit of not generating random variate one at a time which is slower. This quickly becomes noticeable for small `nmax`.

Hope this helps.

---

## Quick compare

Taking @jjc385 `Array[f, {nmax, nmax}]` and @KraZug `g[mat]` with `NestList`.

```
GeneralUtilities`BenchmarkPlot[
 {
  Function[{num},
   NestList[
    With[{rand = RandomInteger[{1, Length[#] + 1}, {2, Length[#]}]},
      ArrayFlatten[{
        {#, Partition[rand[[1]], 1]},
        {{rand[[2]]}, {{0}}}
        }]
      ] &
    ,
    startMatrix,
    num - 1
    ]]
  ,
  Array[f, {#, #}] &,
  NestList[g, {{0, 1}, {0, 0}}, #] &
  },
 Identity,
 Range[3, 20],
 PlotLegends -> {"Edmund", "jjc385", "KraZug"}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it would be simpler to generate an `nmax` by `nmax` matrix from the start, and replace the initial submatrix.

```
mat = Table[If[i == j, 0, RandomInteger[{1, Max[i, j]}] ],
   {i, nmax}, {j, nmax}];
mat[[;; d, ;; d]] = startMatrix;
mat
```

---

**Edit** Actually, with OP's function `f` already created, it's even simpler just to use that:

```
mat = Array[f, {nmax, nmax}]
```

---

Then you could extract the iterative sub-matrices afterward:

```
Table[mat[[;; i, ;; i]], {i, d, Length@mat}]
MatrixForm /@ %
```

Answer (score 1):

`NestList` with an appropriate function for making the next list will work. 
This looks ugly though, sure it can be improved.

```
g[mat_] := 
 Transpose[
  FlattenAt[{Transpose[
     FlattenAt[{mat, RandomInteger[{1, Length[mat]}, Length[mat]]}, 
      1]], Flatten[{RandomInteger[{1, Length[mat]}, Length[mat]], 
      0}]}, 1]]

NestList[g, {{0, 1}, {0, 0}}, 15]
```