# Constructing Array of Matrices

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation

I wanted to create a list of matrices from the following rules:

i- All matrices of the list have diagonal equal to zero.

ii- The first matrix have 2x2 dimension, `m2={{0,1},{0,0}}`

iii- Draw `RandomInteger[{1,2}]`; 2 is dimension of the matrix start

iv- The next matrix (m3) have 3x3 dimensions and the submatrix have same elements of the matrix write in step ii; the other elements are obtained by RandomNumber (step iii) and elments of the step (ii): The elements of the last Column are: `m3[[1,3]]=m2[[1,2]], m3[[2,3]]=m2[[2,2]]`. The elements of the last line are `m3[[3,1]]=m3[[1,1]], m3[[3,2]]=m3[[1,2]]`.

v- The next matrix have dimension 4x4; repeat the same elements of the step iv and draw a new RandomInteger[{1,3}] (3 is the dimension of the matrix in step iv). The other elements are obtnained from the matrix m3 and RandomInteger.

For instance: look the figure below

[image]. 
 I thought in the code below, but is not working

```
nmax = 15 ;(*number of matrices*)
m2 = {{0, 1}, {0, 0}} ;(*The matrix begin - start matrix*)
d = 2(*dimension of the matrix begin*);
q = Table[
  RandomInteger[{1, i}], {i, 2, nmax - 1}](*List of Random Integer*)
f[i_, j_] := 
 If[i <= d && j <= d, m2[[i, j]], 
  If[j == i, 0, 
   If[j > i, With[{s = q[[j - d]]}, mat[[i, s]]], 
    With[{p = q[[i - d]]}, mat[[p, j]]]]]](*Rules*)
mat = Array[f, {nmax, nmax}](*write in variable mat the matrix m2*)
c = Table[
  mat[[;; i, ;; i]], {i, d, 
   Length@mat}];(*generate the list of matrix*)
Table[MatrixForm[c[[i]]], {i, 
  nmax - 1}](*Matrix Form of the list matrix*)
```

Please, somebody help me?

Comment: How is this question significantly different from this one that you already asked ([148762](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148762))? Surely you can modify the answers provided there for this.

Comment: Also you have asked quite a few questions and have not accepted answers on any of them.  Please revisit those questions and accept a suitable answer if one exists. Take [The Tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

I would pad the matrix, and then set the last row and column to the right values:

```
augment[m_, i_] := Module[{new=PadRight[m, Dimensions[m]+1]},
    new[[;;-2, -1]] = m[[All, i]];
    new[[-1, ;;-2]] = m[[i]];
    new
]
```

Then, you can use [`FoldList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldList) to get the matrices. For your example:

```
random = {2, 1, 3, 4};
list = FoldList[augment[#1, #2]&, {{0, 1}, {0, 0}}, random];
list //TeXForm
```

> $\left\{\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  0 & 1 \\
>  0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right),\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  0 & 1 & 1 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right),\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right),\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right),\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)\right\}$

Comment: Is working very well. Thank you very much!!